# After USBGuard having blocked all USB devices including keyboard, is there any way to stop the service?

Tags: security, usb, blocking, keyboard

After USBGuard having blocked all USB devices including keyboard, is there any way to stop the service?

Or will I need to reinstall the system as it is rendered unusable if it is not remotely accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Figured the service can be bypassed as long as the root partition is not encrypted, by mounting the `/usr/lib/systemd/system` directory on another machine and deleting the services' symlink.